# How to use Material design with bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, material-design, bootstrap-4

I am developing a web app, I have been using bootstrap-4 features, then I decided to add material design library to have more features, but unfortunate some features have changed on my page like text colors, font size and buttons appearance. I got confused with this, Is there any rule for may be arrangement of calling the links and scripts files of both bootstrap-4 and material design? or something else regarding on the usage of these frameworks?

Comment: which library you used for material design?

Comment: because of the way bs4 works, all md impls libs require just adding the md lib imp as they usually come with bs4 compiled as part of the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **step by step method** to use **Material with Bootstrap 4**

Step 1:  Create new angular project using Angular CLI command:

```
ng new your-angular-project --style=scss
```

Step 2:

```
cd your-angular-project
```

Step 3:  GitHub npm install

```
npm i angular-bootstrap-md --save
```

Step 4: to app.module.ts add

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot()
    ],
    schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
});
```

Step 5: Make sure that styleExt is set to "scss" in angular-cli.json file, if not change:

```
"styleExt": "css" to "styleExt": "scss"
```

Step 6:

Make sure you have . If you have src/styles.css instead, rename it to .scss.

if you want to change styles in existing project you can use ng set defaults.styleExt scss

Step 7: add below lines to angular-cli.json:

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
    "../node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss",
    "../node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/mdb-free.scss",
    "./styles.scss"
],
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
  "../node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
],
```

Step 8: Update ts.config.json file, add following into tsconfig.json file located in root folder

```
"include": ["node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/**/*.ts",  "src/**/*.ts"],
```

Step 9: install external libs

```
npm install -–save chart.js@2.5.0 font-awesome hammerjs
```

Step 10: Run server

```
ng serve --open
```

for manual and npm configuration, https://mdbootstrap.com/angular/5min-quickstart/

for documentation, https://mdbootstrap.com/, after opening this page, go down you'll find like that and click to see documentation

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at **Material** by Daemonite.

Daemonite's Material UI is a cross-platform and fully responsive front-end interface based on Google Material Design. This lightweight framework is built using Bootstrap 4.

Link :https://github.com/Daemonite/material